# Show the last items of an XML document with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am currently using the code below to read an xml document.

The code outputs all books in the XML document. I'm wondering if it's possible to only show the first 5 books or show a specific book title.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->load( 'books.xml' ); 
  $books = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "books" );
  foreach( $books as $book )
  {
  $authors = $book->getElementsByTagName( "author" );
  $author = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue; 
  $publishers = $book->getElementsByTagName( "publisher" );
  $publisher = $publishers->item(0)->nodeValue; 
  $titles = $book->getElementsByTagName( "title" );
  $title = $titles->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

change your for statement

```
  foreach( $books as $book )
```

to

```
     for( $i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$book = $books[$i];
//Other Logic Here
}
```

That was for First 5 books.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is XPath.

- `/books/book[position() < 5]` returns the first 5 books
- `/books/book[author = 'xyz']` returns all books of a specific author
- `/books/book[title = 'xyz']` returns books of a specific title
- `/books/book[title = 'xyz']/author` returns the author of a book with a specific title

…and so on. See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php